# Search for a String (as an byte[]) in a binary stream

Tags: java, serialization, seek, randomaccessfile

Hi Team, I am trying to find a String "Henry" in a binary file and change the String  to a different string. FYI the file is the output of serialisation of an object. [Original Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232096/how-to-i-read-and-edit-txt-in-a-serialised-file)

I am new to searching bytes and imagined this code would search for my byte[] and exchange it. But it doesn't come close to working it doesn't even find a match.

```
{
    byte[] bytesHenry = new String("Henry").getBytes();
    byte[] bytesSwap = new String("Zsswd").getBytes();

    byte[] seekHenry = new byte[bytesHenry.length];

    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(fileString,"rw");

    long filePointer;
    while (seekHenry != null) {
       filePointer = file.getFilePointer();
       file.readFully(seekHenry);
       if (bytesHenry == seekHenry) {
           file.seek(filePointer);
           file.write(bytesSwap);
           break;
       }
     }
}
```

---

Okay I see the `bytesHenry==seekHenry` problem and will swap to `Arrays.equals( bytesHenry , seekHenry )`

I think I need to move along by -4 byte positions each time i read 5 bytes.

---

Bingo it finds it now

```
    while (seekHenry != null) {
                    filePointer = file.getFilePointer();
                    file.readFully(seekHenry);;
                    if (Arrays.equals(bytesHenry,
                                      seekHenry)) {
                        file.seek(filePointer);
                        file.write(bytesSwap);
                        break;
                    }
                    file.seek(filePointer);
                    file.read();
                }
```

Comment: well at least upvote my original answer if you found it useful for opening this question :)

Comment: I was testing to see if the write worked correctly. ;)

Comment: do you search with a maximun string length?

Comment: if yes, you could read and cache in a ring cache buffer

Comment: for this example its a one off "Henry", but I'm interested hearing a better approach for the future.

Comment: see my answer; you should 1) read all your file into the byte array, 2) search it for a occurrence, 3) if find it, replace it, 4) loop until all your occurrences are replaced. 5) Then write the final byte[] into disk.

Comment: the answer is just for step 2, of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following could work for you, see the method `search(byte[] input, byte[] searchedFor)` which returns the index where the first match matches, or -1.

```
public class SearchBuffer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String charset= "US-ASCII";
        byte[] searchedFor = "ciao".getBytes(charset);
        byte[] input = "aaaciaaaciaojjcia".getBytes(charset);

        int idx = search(input, searchedFor);
        System.out.println("index: "+idx); //should be 8
    }

    public static int search(byte[] input, byte[] searchedFor) {
        //convert byte[] to Byte[]
        Byte[] searchedForB = new Byte[searchedFor.length];
        for(int x = 0; x<searchedFor.length; x++){
            searchedForB[x] = searchedFor[x];
        }

        int idx = -1;

        //search:
        Deque<Byte> q = new ArrayDeque<Byte>(input.length);
        for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
            if(q.size() == searchedForB.length){
                //here I can check
                Byte[] cur = q.toArray(new Byte[]{});
                if(Arrays.equals(cur, searchedForB)){
                    //found!
                    idx = i - searchedForB.length;
                    break;
                } else {
                    //not found
                    q.pop();
                    q.addLast(input[i]);
                }
            } else {
                q.addLast(input[i]);
            }
        }

        return idx;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Fastest way to find a string in a text file with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460684/fastest-way-to-find-a-string-in-a-text-file-with-java/28792225#28792225):

The best realization I've found in MIMEParser: https://github.com/samskivert/ikvm-openjdk/blob/master/build/linux-amd64/impsrc/com/sun/xml/internal/org/jvnet/mimepull/MIMEParser.java

```
/**
  * Finds the boundary in the given buffer using Boyer-Moore algo.
  * Copied from java.util.regex.Pattern.java
  *
  * @param mybuf boundary to be searched in this mybuf
  * @param off start index in mybuf
  * @param len number of bytes in mybuf
  *
  * @return -1 if there is no match or index where the match starts
  */

  private int match(byte[] mybuf, int off, int len) {
```

Needed also:

```
  private void compileBoundaryPattern();
```